# PHP string manipulation using str_replace

Tags: php, rss, str-replace

I have the following code that fetches the contents of an rss feed that I have no control over. Unfortunately it's badly formatted.

```
$curl_result = str_replace("&acirc;", "SOMETHING", $curl_result);
```

What i'm actually trying to replace is the occurences of the string

```
&acirc;€™
```

What's the best way to do this? I was hoping for a simple str_replace + an two extra characters...

Any help much appreciated.

edit - the string is: `&acirc;€™`.

Comment: It's worth reading the [mark-down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) to learn how to format code *as* code (among other helpful tips...). :)

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be an apostrophe.  Use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
mb_convert_encoding($curl_result, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```